# how can I Copy songs from Media library to Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to create an Alarm Application with the Tone set by song from users Music Library. However, I can't find any documentation or example to Copy a song from **Media Library** **->** **Isolated Storage**.All I find is the opposite of what I want to do. Please Help.

Comment: There is no way to get songs from the media library in Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8.

Comment: but there are many applications that use songs from music library such as Music Alarm and others that work very well on windowsphone 8 and 7.5

Comment: Based on their description, they require the app to keep running and just use the `MediaLibrary` API.